# Getting error when connecting to cosmos from dataproc

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm following the below documentation to connect to cosmos from dataproc.
`https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark`

However, I'm getting below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: Direct mode https protocol is not currently supported with PrivateLink. Please use Direct mode TCP protocol instead.
```

Steps I have followed:

```
spark-shell --master yarn --packages "com.microsoft.azure:azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11:1.3.5"


val readConfig = Config(Map(
  "Endpoint" -> "https://xxxxx-cosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443/",
  "Masterkey" -> "xxxxxx",
  "Database" -> "dev-docdb-poc",
  "Collection" -> "staging",
  "SamplingRatio" -> "1.0",
  "query_custom" -> "SELECT * from c"
))

spark.read.cosmosDB(readConfig).show
```

How to resolve this error? Is there a better way to read from cosmos container using dataproc in gcp?

Comment: Have you tried setting `useGatewayMode` to false in your config? There are two ways to connect: gateway/http (max compatibility, slower), and direct/tcp (fastest). Java and C# both support direct/tcp, which is what you should be using. (note: this really has nothing to do with gcp). Also: make sure you're using the latest Spark 3 connector.

Comment: Please use the Spark 3 connector if possible -> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-java-spark-v3

Comment: Thank you MatiasQuaranta and @DavidMakogon. Upgraded the connector to 3.1 and it is working fine